# Slider bar value into textbox

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and need some help for with a little problem.

I have a slider bar and want the selected value to be put into a textbox below, so far I
have managed to show the value under the slider bar.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
-100 <input type="range" min="-100" max="100" step="5"       
onchange="showValue(this.value)" /> 100
<br><span id="value">0</span>
<script>
function showValue(newValue)
{
document.getElementById("value").innerHTML=newValue;
}
</script>
<p id="tbox">
<input type="text">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me and please no jQuery suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Thanks a lot thats exactly what I've been looking for ...and so very simple....and also 
thanks for the onmousemove hint ...very nice

Comment: Just a suggestion: you can add an extra  `onmousemove="showValue(this.value)"` to your range for some elegant functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't tested cross-browser, but this seems to work:

```
<html>
<body>
-100 <input type="range" min="-100" max="100" step="5"
onchange="showValue(this.value)" /> 100
<script>
function showValue(newValue)
{
document.getElementById("value").value=newValue;
}
</script>
<p id="tbox">
<input type="text" id="value">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```